# jQuery on second hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to do something after a second hover event is triggered inside a div?

For example

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="hover-me"></div>
  <div class="hover-me"></div>
  <div class="hover-me"></div>
</div>
```

How can I do something when `.hover-me` is hovered the second time? It should only check for hovers inside the `.items` parent.

Comment: Use a counter and check the counter in `hover` handler

Comment: What should happen in the third time?

Comment: _"Is it possible"_ Of course; what have you tried?

Comment: The counter should be individual for each element or for all elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a counter in the data of each element and increment it on each hover, if it gets to two, do your magic:

HTML:

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="hover-me" data-hovercount="0"></div>
    <div class="hover-me" data-hovercount="0"></div>
    <div class="hover-me" data-hovercount="0"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".hover-me").on('mouseenter', function() {
    var $this = $(this), $this.data('hovercount', parseInt($this.data('hovercount')) + 1);
    if ($this.data('hovercount') == 2) {
        //do something.
    }
});
```

Comment: I think there's no need of `parseInt` on data

Comment: will the data attr be `int`? because `"1" + 1 == "11"`

Comment: When the data is set by jQuery it don't need to be parsed to int, but when added in HTML, it needs